# Inequalities in Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I come across with the following inequality if $\gamma < \frac{\alpha}{4}$ then $|\tau|^{2\gamma} \leq c(\gamma) \frac{1+|\tau|^{\alpha} }{1+|\tau|^{\alpha-2\gamma} }$. I tried in many ways but I couldn't find this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with
$$
|\tau|^{2\gamma}
(1+|\tau|^{\alpha-2\gamma})
=
|\tau|^{2\gamma}
+
|\tau|^{\alpha}
.
$$
By Young's inequality, we get
$$
|\tau|^{2\gamma}
\le \frac12+
\frac12
|\tau|^{4\gamma}.
$$
Due to $\gamma < \alpha/4$,
we get
$$
|\tau|^{4\gamma}
\le
1
+
|\tau|^{\alpha}.
$$
Hence,
$$
|\tau|^{2\gamma}
(1+|\tau|^{\alpha-2\gamma})
\le
1
+
\frac32|\tau|^{\alpha}
\le
\frac32 (1+|\tau|^{\alpha}).
$$
This shows your inequality with $c = 3/2$.